# Deleting multiple entries with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, unit-testing, nunit

I have a test:

```
[Test, Order(1)]
public async Task routes()
{
    var allRoutes = _context.Routes.Where(r => r.Distance == 9999).ToList();
    Assert.IsNotEmpty(allRoutes); 
}
```

which passes but:

```
[Test, Order(2)]
public async Task SelectAllRoutesAndDelete()
{
    var routesToDelete = _context.Routes.Where(r => r.Distance == 9999).ToList();

    _context.Routes.RemoveRange(routesToDelete);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    var remainingRoutes = _context.Routes.Where(r => r.Distance == 9999).ToList();
    Assert.IsEmpty(remainingRoutes);
}
```

fails and does not delete the routes.

The issue has to be here:

```
_context.Routes.RemoveRange(routesToDelete);
```

Comment: Do you have an exception?

Comment: Yes: 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException : The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

Comment: Add the definition and any mapping configuration for this Route entity.  How many routes are you expecting to delete in your test scenario?